# Log4Net AdoNetAppender - Formatting log date to get seconds included

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

My issue is that my Database logging does not display seconds (default format seems to be "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:00".
Is there any way to change this and get something with seconds at least (miliseconds would be a plus)?

Here is my appender config:

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="data source=MyDB;initial catalog=LogSpace;integrated security=True;persist security info=True;Application Name=&quot;MyApp &quot;" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>
</appender>
```

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT**: Just as suggested by leppie, I checked my Date type in database, which was smalldatetime. I changed it to datetime and now my logs are as expected (with seconds & milliseconds)

Comment: I have the exact same config as you have and I see seconds to two decimal places in the logs - as it's logged to a `datetime2(2)` column. What data type is your Date column?

Comment: Ah, well done. Indeed, my Date column type was "smalldatetime". I changed to "datetime" and now the date format is correct (includes seconds).
Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 5):

Change @log_date parameter like this:

```
          <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@log_date"/>
            <dbType value="DateTime"/>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" 
              value="%date{yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff}"/>
          </parameter>
```